# Getting around email restrictions with hosting providers

Tags: php, pear

So my hosting provider is limiting emails sent out to 2 at a time, which means no array of emails.Right now I'm using Pear to send html emails to multiple users who sign up together.

Is there a solution to loop through the mail() function multiple times ultimately sending out multiple emails? How will the performance be?

The hosting company actually suggested we look for some solution to by pass their restrictions, but i don't know where to look.

Thanks

Comment: @Adam - can you clarify what is `limiting emails sent out to 2 at a time` ? Per script execution only allow two emails ?

Comment: which hosting provider are you using?

Comment: yes per script execution... netfirms

Comment: In this case, try [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php), in single script, you can spawn multiple processes that doing two emails

Comment: how are you sending out your mail?  when you say multiple users. do you mean multiple email account but just sending the same content to them?

Comment: If this is a serious need, consider a JangoMail account, as they have an awesomely simple mail sending API (and it will get delivered reliably).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just iterate over the array of email addresses? I assume your use case is more complex than this, but it should get you on the right path:

```
<?php
foreach ($emails_array as $email)
{
    mail($email, ....); //or whatever your mail call is
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried it and it works... but how reliable will this be with 10 emails?

Comment: @Adam, Just read your comment reply above. If they are limiting per script execution, this won't do anything for you.

Comment: maybe im not clear on the terminology... but one mail() with an array of emails won't do... I put the mail() in a loop and it works.

Answer (score 1):

PEAR's [Mail_Queue package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Queue/) comes to mind here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cron job to setup sending out when the hourly limit hits.

or,

you can use mail chimp or constant contact to do the job for you.